# JavaFX: Bound value cannot be set exception

Tags: exception, javafx

In my javafx application I have created a table view where I have some projects.  If the projects are there in the table view, then the delete button should be enabled, otherwise delete button should be disabled.

Now the problem is that when I select the project and click the delete button it's throwing the following exception.

How can I solve this?

This is my tableview code.

```java
tableViewProject.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        Project selectedProject = tableViewProject.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedProject != null) {
            currentProject = selectedProject;
            propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("projectManagerController.projectIsSelected", null, selectedProject);
            btn_remove_project.setDisable(false);
        } else {
            btn_remove_project.setDisable(true);
        }
    }
});
```

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Button.disable : A bound value cannot be set.
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:140)
at javafx.scene.Node.setDisable(Node.java:1543)
at com.virtusa.tempo.server.ui.controllers.ProjectManagerController$3.handle(ProjectManagerController.java:131)
at com.virtusa.tempo.server.ui.controllers.ProjectManagerController$3.handle(ProjectManagerController.java:124)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3471)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3399)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3767)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$355/919089086.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$39/1633781598.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory - `A bound value cannot be set`. It means that if you have used binding on one of the property then you should not manually set the value. Are you binding the `disableProperty()` of the `btn_remove_project`  somewhere?

Answer (score 18):

You are probably binding it to a property somewhere. This is a one way binding.  In order to send information back from the control you need to change it to bindBidirectional

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem in a JavaFX ImageView when it bind to a property:

```java
imageViewProfile.imageProperty().bind(imageProperty);
```

to unbind and fix this error "JavaFX: Bound value cannot be set exception
", I have to unbind with:

```java
imageViewProfile.imageProperty().unbind();
```